# WP_Query for ACF meta_value with taxonomy id

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy, meta-key

I have two custom post types.

I have row witch meta_key and meta_value from ACF field and I need query with all posts with checked ACF taxonomy field ( the taxonomy from another custom post types )

### meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value

1         | 2         |some_key    | a:2:{i:0;s:3:"196";i:1;s:3:"197";}

196 and 197 in meta_value are ID taxonomy from custom post type (nr 1) that are checked in post from other custom post type (nr 2).

I need WP_Query with all posts from custom post type nr 2 with checked taxonomy field example 196.

What is the correct way ??